# Regex how to match all except a group of dots?

Tags: regex

I want to match all except a group of consecutive dots.
Is it possible?

This is what I have so far. `[^(\.)]{1,}|(\d*\.\d+)`

```
................May y/y...Apr y/y...May m/m...Apr m/m\n
Total...........22.5......20.4......2.6.......2.8\n
mining..........12.4......12.8......0.8.......4.4\n
manufacturing...19.9......18.4......2.1.......2.7\n
electricity.....99.2......77.6......11.8......5.2\n
water supply....4.1.......4.1.......0.0.......0.0\n
```

I do not want dots at the beginning of a decimal numbers.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's all over the place so I'm not sure if you really need to match all of this, but you could use `(\d+\.\d+)|[^.]+` to achieve what you are after.

Comment: In the `(\d*\.\d+)` part, why are you using `*` instead of `+` for the first number? Do you expect decimal numbers of the form `.4` (as a short-hand for `0.4`), where the distinction to `4` only becomes clear due to indentation?

Comment: Also, have you chosen to write `{1,}` in the front part and `+` in the latter part on purpose? Using such synonyms rather than sticking to one way of writing throughout the expression makes the expression unnecessarily hard to grasp IMHO.

Comment: As the data has columns with fixed widths, it looks like it would be simpler to cut each line into columns and trim the trailing dots.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, @JvdV - thank you. I`m relatively a new guy in regexes..

Comment: Completely agree with @O.R.Mapper. The use of `*` in the second match with `\d` is the culprit. IMHO, you have to use `xxx.xxx` format to catch all these values with the above regex. Otherwise, it will be difficult to differentiate whether to use it as `xxx` or `.xxx`.

Comment: @Bob If you let us know more about the scenario where this data needs to be parsed and the data structure in needs to be stored in, in particular the programming language being used, someone might post an answer that just happened to include sufficient code to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that "consecutive" means that the sequence never starts with a dot, never ends with it and one single dot is always a part of matching sequence, the expression should be as simple as [this](https://regex101.com/r/YO78hm/1): `/[^.]+\.?[^.]+/gm`